# delete empty quotes and pattern before it in python

Tags: python

I have a file as below, whenever there is a key with empty value, I want to delete the key and the empty quotes

My file

```
<items="20" product="abc" condition="new">
<items="10" product="" condition="new">
<items="50" product="xyz" condition="">
<items="" product="mno" condition="fair">
```

desired output

```
<items="20" product="abc" condition="new">
<items="10" condition="new">
<items="50" product="xyz">
<product="mno" condition="fair">
```

I tried somehting like this, this deleted only the quotes. I want to delete the quotes and the value before "="

```
f= open('test.txt','r') 
A1=f.read()

for i in A1:
    if i=="''":
        A1.remove(i)
    print A1
    break
```

Comment: Use an XML parser.

Comment: I'm assuming you are running into a situation where you modify the iterator that you are using. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593585/dictionary-changes-size-during-iteration is a similar issue. You cannot change the list you are iterating over in a for each loop

Comment: Also, you variable `i` will contain the full string. So your code would only remove the line if it was entirely blank. Which can not be as there is (if i'm not mistaken) still a newline character at the end.

Comment: Also, outside of python this can be done fairly quickly (normally) with a simple find & replace sed script. `s/ [A-z]*=""/ /g` is what pops to my mind first. Possibly too broad, but should still work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```py
import re

with open('test.txt','r') as A1:
   for i in A1:
       print(re.sub('[a-z-]+=\"\" *', '', i))
```

Comment: this works fine but if the items or product names have "-" this is not working. I tested it on this <items-list="" product-item="xyz" condition=""> instead of outputting <product-item="xyz"> it outputted <items-product-item="xyz" >

Comment: Thank you, but I dont see any changes in the code you posted.

Comment: I changed [a-z] in the regex to [a-z-].

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```
with open('test.txt','r+') as f:
     for line in f:
          Line=line[1:len(line)-1]
          L=Line.split()

          for k in L: 
               if("" not in k):
                     f.write(k)
               f.write(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to pass the lines through:

```
with open('in_file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def process_line(line):
    line = line.split('<')[1].rsplit('>')[0]
    valids = [val for val in line.split(' ') if '""' not in val]
    line = '<{}>\n'.format(' '.join(valids))
    return line

with open('out_file', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(process_line(line))
```

Comment: I tried this , got index error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    f.write(process_line(line))
  File "test1.py", line 4, in process_line
    line = line.split('<')[1].rsplit('>')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex,

```
with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as f_in:
        with open('tmp_clean.txt', 'w') as f_outfile:
            f_out = csv.writer(f_outfile)
            for line in f_in:
                line = line.strip()
                row = []
                if bool(re.search('(.*="")', line)):
                    line = re.sub('[a-z]+=\"\"', '',line)
                    row.append(line)
                else:
                    row.append(line)
                f_out.writerow(row)
```